# Google cloud gsutil Problem transferier Split Data cut in linux

Tags: split, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I split a big file on google cloud VM using `split -b 2m MY_BIG_FILE`. And then push these files on to cloud storage 'bucket'. After that, I downloaded them to my local Mac with the command `gsutil -m gs://MY_DATA_DIR MY_LOCAL_DIR`.

The problem is, when I tried restore the downloaded pieces back into the original big file (by using `cat SPLITTED_FILES > RESTORED_FILE`) it failed and prompt strange output.

[Update] The output is lik the following:
[image]
It's strange that the following two ways of operations work fine for me:

1. split file on local Mac, upload using `gsutil` and then restore on google cloud VM;
2. split file on VM, download using `gcloud compute scp` and then restore on local Mac.

Could anybody help?

Comment: How big is your file and what are you getting as "strange output"? I just tried to replicate your scenario following the steps you've indicated but I get everything ok.

Comment: I've just updated my question by adding a screen shot. Yesterday when I was in the company, it happend for either bigger file (653M) or smaller one (600K). But now when I'm at home with better network, everything's OK too. But the problem was there for sure and made me stuck all afternoon. Really drive me crazy.